# How do I accept data on the backside of a utility app, and then how do I let users modify that data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I accept data on the backside of a utility app, and then how do I let users modify that data? I've tried all sorts of tutorials, but to no avail. If you need further information let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by "accept data"? Do you want to allow the user to input data? Read data from a web service? What is the higher-level goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a user to input data yes

Comment: Input where?  On the iphone's touch screen, website?  What kind of data? This question isn't very clear.  What do you mean backside of the app?  Have you built and run all of Apple's sample apps, maybe one of them does something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Is it for a server-client app? If so then you need to parse your data and communicate whith the web or anything else

Answer (score 0):

Summary:  Values from inputs on the flipside view should be cached into model class(es), which the mainside view will make use of.

Each of the values from the flipside view inputs needs to be available off the flipside view.  These must therefore be captured in some data class(es), usually custom, which keep the data available.  These classes will also provide the defaults, and any values held over from the previous invocation of the application, for the mainside view to make use of.

Key to making this work is to set the input views' values from the models' values when going into the flipside (eg in the flipside controller's "viewWillAppear"), and set the models' values when coming off the flipside (eg in the flipside controller's "viewWillDisappear").

That's the high-level overview.  If your focus now shifts to implementation details, mine the sample apps.  They should give you enough hints -- they did for me.